# Не устанавливается Windows 10 на SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, uefi, ntfs

По какой-то причине не устанавливается винда на ссд-шник, сначала идёт распаковка всех нужных файлов, но при плановой перезагрузке ПК установка просто начинается заново.

UPD: Пробовал менять тип разделов с MBR на GPT, не помогло. Также пытался перенести уже установленную винду на ссд, но это тоже нее помогло.

Comment: Приоритет загрузки в биосе настроен на установочный носитель, видимо?

Comment: @andreymal 
Приоритет загрузки при начале установки менялся на саму флешку, с которой устанавливаю. Пробовал вручную менять приоритет, пробовал доставать флешку во время перезагрузки - положительного эффекта нет.

Comment: Откуда же начинается установка при перезагрузке, если установочная флешка не вставлена?